# Why am I getting NaN for integer?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

This is my code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  noStroke();
}

var momentum = [0, 0]; //x and y speed
var pos = [650, 300]; //player x and y
var enemiesX = []; //enemies x's
var enemiesY = []; //enemies y's

function draw() {
  background(200);
  momentum[0] = (pos[0] - mouseX) / 5;
  pos[0] =+ momentum;
  fill(115);
  ellipse(pos[0], pos[1], 30, 30);
  text(pos[0] + ", " + pos[1], 20, 20);
}
```

I am using arrays to compact similar x's and y's that are paired. I was testing with the text function, and I realized the first of ***every*** array is NaN. I know its this:

```
  momentum[0] = (pos[0] - mouseX) / 5;
  pos[0] =+ momentum;
```

but what is wrong?

Also, before people spam this with flags saying its a duplicate, the simplicity means no other question of this nature had a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. The first is that you're using `=+` instead of `+=`. The second is that `momentum` is an array, not a number. This is what your code is doing right now in the two lines you highlighted:

- Evaluate `(pos[0] - mouseX) / 5`
- Save that value in the 0 position of the `momentum` array.
- Evaluate `+momentum`
- Save that value in the 0 position of the `pos` array.

At the third bullet point, what happens is that `+momentum` evaluates to `NaN`. Then you're saving that value in the `pos` array. The first of the two lines is fine. I think that what you're looking to do is to add `momentum[0]` to `pos[0]`, which can be done like this:

```
  pos[0] += momentum[0];
```

I'm not certain what you intend, but my guess is that you want to make the circle go *toward* the cursor, not away from it. In that case, you have the sign of the momentum wrong, it should be like this:

```
  momentum[0] = (mouseX - pos[0]) / 5;
  pos[0] += momentum[0];
```

Comment: hehe, forgot all about this. Wow, my code's got some issues. Maybe I'll mess around with this again

Answer (score 1):

Where is `mouseX` defined? It it's `undefined`, any number plus `undefined` will equal zero.

Additonally, `=+` is not the same as `+=` and will cause further issues

Comment: It is not necessary to define `mouseX`. The question is tagged <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. `mouseX` is a built-in, read only variable.

Comment: Okay thank you for explaining where `mouseX` is defined. I did ask where it was defined because I wasn't sure. My apologies, I interpreted the processing tag as much more generic than it is, and I was unaware I was enabled to receive questions for it.

Comment: I see. In this case it's more exactly [`p5.js`](https://p5js.org/). That's the javascript version of "Processing".

Answer (score 0):

Use `parsetInt` to avoid `NaN` and add further check for `NaN`

```
   createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    noStroke();
}

var momentum = [0, 0]; //x and y speed
var pos = [650, 300]; //player x and y
var enemiesX = []; //enemies x's
var enemiesY = []; //enemies y's

function draw() {
    background(200);
    mouseX = parseInt(mouseX);
    if(mouseX === NaN){
        alert('Not a number exception');
    }
    else{
        momentum[0] = (pos[0] - mouseX) / 5;
        pos[0] =+ momentum;
        fill(115);
        ellipse(pos[0], pos[1], 30, 30);
        text(pos[0] + ", " + pos[1], 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I’ll get try when I get a chance, but I assume it works, as OpenProccesing will sometimes give decimal mouseX and my mouseY.

Comment: While dealing with numbers always use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` and add type check, it will make your code typesafe.

Comment: I edited the code (not the post) because isNaN(); should be used. I also changed the alert to text written on the screen as to prevent getting spammed with alerts. 3rd thing is that the mouseX would just change right back to its original value after being parsed, so I made a new variable parMouseX (parsed MouseX). But what I really commented for was because it simply does not work. I tried parseInt and ParseFloat, but neither of them work.

Comment: can you create some jsFiddle, and post the link of that here, so that I can get where is it going wrong.

Comment: here's the open processing link: https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/779783